# getPlaylist returns an array with only one video when using the Youtube IFrame API

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, video, youtube

I'm trying to make a webpage that will load a given Youtube playlist and play a random video from it.

I'm struggling getting the playlist information from the API as when I run

```
player.getPlaylist()
```

the API returns an array of one element (the currently cued video) every time, regardless of the cued video or playlist.
My JavaScript is an almost 100% copy/paste from the API documentation and I can't work out why I can't get the full list of videos in the playlist.

```
<script>

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode
    .insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: {
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLbIZ6k-SE9SiarIg09JXUdK2kDX5_OB25',
        autoplay: 0,
        controls: 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log(event.target.getPlaylist());
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
      done = true;
      console.log('Video Finished');
      stopVideo();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Can anybody lend a hand and point to my mistake or in the right direction?

Comment: This answer taught me how to get all video IDs from a YouTube playlist using javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56723612/470749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the playlist is not actually cued when loaded this way but only the first video. This is confirmed by `getPlaylist()` returning only one video and the `onStateChange` event not firing once the player has loaded.

We can however force the player to cue the playlist with `cuePlaylist()`. What is described below can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9en9bwy7/4/).

We modify the constructor to load nothing:

```
playerVars: {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1
},
```

We modify `onPlayerReady()` to cue the playlist:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.cuePlaylist({
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLbIZ6k-SE9SiarIg09JXUdK2kDX5_OB25',
    });
}
```

We modify `onPlayerStateChange()` to check for the `CUED` state and get the playlist when it fires:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
        console.log(event.target.getPlaylist());
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED && !done) {
        done = true;
        console.log('Video Finished');
        stopVideo();
    }
}
```

After which the console outputs this:

```
Array [ "j_OyHUqIIOU", "PK8dsAeMmPk", "lfvceHUBWnU", "Xz5z1hBxejg",
        "OubvTOHWTms", "5WKU7gG_ApU", "XjwO9InuFJk", "lNqChN3WHh8" ]
```